# Create react app proxy doesn't redirect request

Tags: reactjs, proxy, backend, create-react-app

I have created react app with [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

So the backed server listens on port `5000`. The react server listens on port `3000`.

I added this line `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` to package JSON. 
Now when I do a request like this:

```
GET /api/hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.102
Content-Type: application/json
```

to the react app. I get this message:

```
+IPD,420:HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 148
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 11:18:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/hello</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a link to the proj files : https://github.com/RadoslavMarinov/stack-show

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the mistake I have made. I misunderstood the create-react-app documentation.

It says:

> Any unrecognized request without a `text/html accept header` will be redirected to the specified proxy.

Instead of putting `Accept: application/json` in the request header I put `Content-Type: application/json`. Which is wrong.